# Multiplying All Combination in Lists in Python

Tags: python, multiplication

I am trying to multiply all combinations of the numbers in 2 lists in python.

For Example

list(abc) and list(xyz) would return
a*x
a*y
a*z
b*x
b*y
b*z
c*x
c*y
c*z

I am quite new to python and so I do not have much experience.

Comment: `itertools.product`?? or a simple nested loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this :

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [10, 100, 1000]
l3 = [ x*y for x in l1 for y in l2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]  
l2 = [10, 100, 1000]  
l3 = [i * j for i, j in zip(l1, l2)]
```